ODR-use a member function of a template class only if it is valid
I need to define a member function __say_hi on a class template, which will not be called anywhere, but still need to be kept by my clang-based frontend. To do so, I add a constexpr static member which holds the address of the function.
The problem is that the __say_hi might not compile if the template parameter (for example because T is not copy-able, but that might be for another reason). So I need to define the static member holding the address only if __say_hi compiles fine.
For example:

template<typename T>
struct foo_t {

  const char * __say_hi() const { 
     T copy(m_t); // <-- needs a copy constructor for T.
     return "hi";
  } // <-- this function won't be called anywhere, but must not be removed from the AST.

   static constexpr auto __ODR_use = &foo_t::__say_hi; // <-- this ODR-uses the function, thus it will not be removed from the AST.

  T m_t;
};

struct non_copyable_t { 
  non_copyable_t(non_copyable_t const &) = delete;
};

int main() {
   foo_t<int> f1; // OK, int is copyable.
   // foo_t<non_copyable_t> f2; // KO, T needs to be copyable.
}

How can I ODR-use __say_hi only if it compiles (C++11 only)?
I tried using SFINAE to check for the member existence, but solution such as this one fails as the template is always true, even if said function doesn't compile.
Edit foo_t is part of library, so I can't know all the types it will be instantiated with, and therefore I can't write specialization for those.

You can't. There is nothing in the language to test for validity of an instantiation. Also, __say_hi and __ODR_use are both reserved identifier for the compiler/standard library that user code shall not use.

I also do not expect there to be any compiler-specific extensions that allow to test for this.

What for do you need the compiler to emit an unused function, especially if it isn't even really known whether or not it shall be emitted? I suspect that it will be easier to solve your original problem another way, whatever it is.

Note: if you delete the copy constructor of non_copyable_t, you should at least define its default constructor, otherwise you can't instantiate a class that has a member of type non_copyable_t

Ah wait, you say "but still need to be kept by my clang-based frontend". So this is specifically about internal representation in clang tooling. What exactly do you mean here? What exactly is missing in the AST that you want to see? You can see the definition of __say_hi just fine in the AST obviously.

"fails as the template is always true" Whereas you cannot check validity of __say_hi, you might test manually its requirement (std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value)

@user17732522 as you can see here: https://godbolt.org/z/Kne4xK89x, without the __ODR_use variable, the __say_hi method is absent from the AST.

"still need to be kept by my clang-based frontend." You should probably be clearer on that part. look like a XY problem currently.

@Dorian The definition of the function is there in the AST either way. Obviously no instantiation. But why do you need that in the AST if there is no such instantiation in the program? What is the point?

I see -CXXMethodDecl 0xd264b50 <line:4:3, line:7:3> line:4:16 __say_hi 'const char *() const' implicit_instantiation implicit-inline instantiated_from 0xd243418 without ODR usage Demo.

@user17732522 The function "__say_hi" will be "called" by a runtime engine, operating on intermediate representation coming from the clang-AST. At this point, the IR the engine operates on has nothing to do with the clang AST, so the "__say_hi" function needs to follow the same route as the rest of the code.

@Jarod42 the method has no body at this point

Maybe you are looking for something like ClassTemplateDecl::AddSpecialization. the wanted function is not in the AST, but you could probably get the information you want from it.

"by a runtime engine, operating on intermediate representation"
Waait - so you are not even talking about an actual compiled C++ program here but rather you want to interpret some intermediary result that could do whatever it wants?

@user17732522 it seems that what I want to do is impossible. Do you want to say that in an answer that I'll accept or do you prefer me to do it ?

@Dorian You can answer yourself.

It seems like this is not possible. To quote @user17732522, "there is nothing in the language to test the validity of an instantiation."
